# xul doesn't export this method `JS_BeginRequest@@YAXPAUJSContext@@@Z` after updating to Firefox 46 GeckoFX 45

Tags: c#, firefox, geckofx, webidl

I am trying to use Firefox 46.0 SDK for GeckoFX45. I was able to find the changed uuid "Guid id" but after updating to Firefox 46 SDK I got this crash in this line :

https://github.com/EbramTawfik/GeckoFX/blob/master/Geckofx-Winforms/GeckoWebBrowser.WinForms.cs#L153

Message :
System.AccessViolationException
HResult=0x80004003
Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Then I was able to generate the c# file for the IDLs:

Using this tool :
https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/idlimp/src/default/

And the WebIDLs Using This tool : 
https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/webidltogeckofxbindings/src/default/

but I am getting this error:

System.EntryPointNotFoundException: **'Unable to find an entry point named '?JS_BeginRequest@@YAXPAUJSContext@@@Z'** in DLL 'xul'.'

and I found the reason is that the newer version for xul doesn't export this method `JS_BeginRequest@@YAXPAUJSContext@@@Z`

So I don't know if there a specific way to rebuild this xul.dll to export these methods? or is the method deprecated in the newer version for xul.dll?! and if it's deprecated what should I use instead of it ?!

Comment: I admire that you're attempting this project, and many people would also like to have it. But I don't think a series of stackoverflow questions is going to be the way to get it done. On the bright side, there are plans for us (SIL) to update geckofx this year.

Comment: What is your suggestion to get this done? I created a mirror on GitHub https://github.com/EbramTawfik/GeckoFX and I hope we can get something done soon ..

Comment: I've only see two people manage these upgrades in recent years. We are expecting one of them, my colleague, to attempt the update later this year. That will then show up on the bitbucket site. I don't want to discourage you from trying, just want convey that it's not normally a straight-forward process.

Comment: @JohnHatton I was able to generate the c# file for the IDLs and the WebIDLs .. but I am getting this error **System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named '?JS_BeginRequest@@YAXPAUJSContext@@@Z' in DLL 'xul'.'** and I found the reason is that the newer version for xul doesn't export this method .. `?JS_BeginRequest@@YAXPAUJSContext@@@Z` .. so how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XulFx it's based on Firefox 52:

https://bitbucket.org/vmas/xulfx/src/default/

and you can download releases from here :

https://bitbucket.org/vmas/xulfx/downloads/